# Add jquery cookie to background changer

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-plugins, setcookie

Hey guys need much appreciated help.. I have tried to add cookies to the following Jquery body background changer code using the Jquery cookie plugin to no avail. The code works fine just no cookies to retain selection.

Thanks a lot everyone.

```
jQuery('#stlChanger .stBgs a').click(function(){
    var bgBgCol = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery('#stlChanger .stBgs a').removeClass('current');
    jQuery('body').css({backgroundColor:'#ffffff'});
    jQuery(this).addClass('current');
    jQuery('body').css({backgroundImage:'url(' + bgBgCol + ')'});
    if (jQuery(this).hasClass('bg_t')){
        jQuery('body').css({backgroundRepeat:'repeat', backgroundPosition:'50% 0', backgroundAttachment:'scroll'});
    } else {
        jQuery('body').css({backgroundRepeat:'repeat', backgroundPosition:'50% 0', backgroundAttachment:'scroll'});
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: can you share the code where you tried to use cookie plugin

Comment: where and how are you setting the cookie?

Comment: using it locally on my machine. I will post a link when it goes online in a few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery('#stlChanger .stBgs a').click(function(){
    var bgBgCol = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery('#stlChanger .stBgs a.current').removeClass('current');

    jQuery('body').css({backgroundColor:'#ffffff'});
    jQuery(this).addClass('current');
    jQuery('body').css({backgroundImage:'url(' + bgBgCol + ')'});

    //Assuming this is how the cookie value is set in your cookie plugin
    //We set the href value of the clicked element to the cookie, since it is the only identifier to identify the clicked element
    $.cookie('stlchanger-bg', bgBgCol)

    if (jQuery(this).hasClass('bg_t')){
        jQuery('body').css({backgroundRepeat:'repeat', backgroundPosition:'50% 0', backgroundAttachment:'scroll'});
    } else {
        jQuery('body').css({backgroundRepeat:'repeat', backgroundPosition:'50% 0', backgroundAttachment:'scroll'});
    }
    return false;
});

jQuery(function($){
    //When the page is reloaded the cookie value is read and we trigger a click event on the matched anchor element
    var bgBgCol = $.cookie('stlchanger-bg');
    if(bgBgCol){
        jQuery('#stlChanger .stBgs a[href="' + bgBgCol + '"]').trigger('click');
    }
})
```

Comment: Wow! worked like a charm man.. I appreciate the swift reply and help.